# How to enable switching Hybrid Intel/ATi with mux on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.10, 10.10, ati, kernel, hybrid-graphics

I have notebook with hybrid intel/ati HD5650 graphic (with mux). I want to install previous kernel 2.6.35 like on ubuntu 10.10 because on that kernel a can switch my graphic without any problem with driver from ati webpage version 10.7 (if my memory doesn't wrong).
Can I do it? How?
I've looked at several webpages but there are no solution for mux hybrid graphic (manually switching)
Maybe from this post can help for developing switching graphic adaptable from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I have the same setup and was never able to get it to work with the ATI drivers (fglrx). I would love to hear how managed to switch between graphics cards back on 10.10. Did you use vga_switcheroo or FGLRX?

Comment: I'm using fglrx, downloaded from ati website. Now I'm only use my discrete graphic only in the BIOS with fglrx.

Comment: Im using fglrx. But now I hope on mesa driver, do you have tried vga_switcheroo with mesa?

Comment: Yes, I've been running Radeon/Mesa for a few months now (upgraded kernel from the [mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and Mesa from [oibaf(13.10+)](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers)/[pali(12.04)](https://launchpad.net/~pali/+archive/graphics-drivers)) and I've played around a bit with vgaswitcheroo. It did work but I had some critical issues that would have needed a lot of time to fix.  Because I didn't have that time I kept using the notebook in discrete only mode and still do.

Comment: Maybe in the future when I eventually switch to 14.04 LTS (~Dec. 2014?) I might find some time to get it to work 100%. If I do so I will post an answer here with all the steps I took.

Comment: 14.04 will lauch on April I tought. Now I'm using from oibaf too on my 13.10,but I haven't tried vgaswitchero yet. I'm not programmer, so what can I do is via trial and error. I'm glad you work on improving this.
Btw, what the critical issue facing you?

Comment: Yes, 14.04 will launch in April but due to time constraints and a busy study schedule I will likely have to wait until winter to upgrade my system. As for the critical issues, I am not quite sure anymore. It's been a while but I think my main issue was with suspend mode: As far as I remember I got kernel panics when recovering from suspend, which made it necessary to hard-reset the notebook.